# How can I make the time difference for each user different?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my script I want to get the last send_time of the user that is logged in. If this send_time is at least a 10 minute time difference with the current time, he will be able to post something new, otherwise he will get an error message.

Though, when I try this, **nobody** will be able to post for at least 10 minutes since the last post someone made.

```
$email = $_SESSION['login'];
if ($link)
 {
 $check="SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, send_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS 'diff' FROM bloopp WHERE email = '$email' ORDER BY bloopp_id DESC LIMIT 1" or die("Error " . mysqli_error($check));
 $res = mysqli_query($link, $check) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($res));
 $data = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if($data['diff'] <= "10")
   {
   echo "You posted not so long ago.";
   }
  else
   {
   $sql="INSERT INTO bloopp (bloopp, browser, medium, send_time, email) VALUES ('$bloopp', '$browser', 'desktop', NOW(), '$email')";
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
    if($result)
     {
     header('Location: index.php');
     }
     else
     {
      echo "Something has gone wrong. We’re sorry.";
     }
    }
 }
else
 {
 echo "ERROR";
 }
```

Comment: Are you comparing to a string? :-)

Comment: why you are not using sessions+cookie to keep status? do you want user not be able to post even if he/she had logout and login (before 10 minutes from last post he had made?

Comment: @MartyMcVry I'm comaring the current time and the last send_time of the logged in user. At least this what I meant to do.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT`ing the time difference directly from your database? What's the value that is being returned?

Comment: If I want to echo $data['diff'], I get this error: unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: `$check="SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, send_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS 'diff' FROM bloopp WHERE email = '$email' ORDER BY bloopp_id DESC LIMIT 1" or die("Error " . mysqli_error($check));` --> remove the `or die`-thingie here... No need for that when assigning a value to a string!

Comment: Okay, I did, but won't work. Do I maybe have to ORDER first and then do the WHERE-clause? I can't figure out why, but I think it has to do with the WHERE-clause that won't work?